# How to Add a date at the beginning of month-year in a loop in Python/ colab?

Tags: python, arrays, string, datetime, pivot

I need your kind suggestions with a table creation.

I have a table that looks like this.

| Month | Department | Total Expenditure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |

And this goes on till May-22 for DOJ and 12 other departments.

I cannot pivot this table, because having duplicates in the first column where the date is missing
Tableau will add the numbers up, and Python will throw an error such as

```
ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape
```

Every month has 12 entries only (12 days a month). I want to add numbers 1 to 12 at the beginning of each Month column so the entries have a unique ID that i can use for `df1.pivot(index='Month',columns='Department', values='Total Expenditure Estimate')`

The new table should look like

| Month | Department | Total Expenditure |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1-Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 2-Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 3-Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 4-Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 5-Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 6-Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 7-Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 8-Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 9-Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 10-Jan-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 11-Jan-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 12-Jan-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 1-Feb-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 2-Feb-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 3-Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 4-Feb-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 5-Feb-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 6-Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 7-Feb-18 | DOJ | 625000 |
| 8-Feb-18 | DOJ | 975000 |
| 9-Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 10-Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 11-Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |
| 12-Feb-18 | DOJ | 650000 |

I will appreciate your kind suggestions. Please kindly help me out and advise how to fix this column. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["Month"] = (
    (df.groupby(["Month", "Department"])["Month"].cumcount() + 1).astype(str)
    + "-"
    + df["Month"]
)
```

Prints:

```
        Month Department  Total Expenditure
0    1-Jan-18        DOJ             625000
1    2-Jan-18        DOJ             975000
2    3-Jan-18        DOJ             650000
3    4-Jan-18        DOJ             625000
4    5-Jan-18        DOJ             975000
5    6-Jan-18        DOJ             650000
6    7-Jan-18        DOJ             625000
7    8-Jan-18        DOJ             975000
8    9-Jan-18        DOJ             650000
9   10-Jan-18        DOJ             625000
10  11-Jan-18        DOJ             975000
11  12-Jan-18        DOJ             650000
12   1-Feb-18        DOJ             625000
13   2-Feb-18        DOJ             975000
14   3-Feb-18        DOJ             650000
15   4-Feb-18        DOJ             625000
16   5-Feb-18        DOJ             975000
17   6-Feb-18        DOJ             650000
18   7-Feb-18        DOJ             625000
19   8-Feb-18        DOJ             975000
20   9-Feb-18        DOJ             650000
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  The problem is now , month order is broken and data is missing. with df1=df1.pivot(index='Month',columns='Department', values='Total Expenditure Estimate') I get missing values. I have included the output in the question.